# Incompatible pointer types sending User* to parameter of type UserProfile*

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ application with latest SDK.

I have these two methods.

On `UserPreferences` class.

```
+ (User*)getUserFromUserPreferences;
```

On `ProfileViewController` class:

```
- (void)showUserData:(UserProfile*)userToShow;
```

And an `UserProfile` that inherits from `User`:

```
@interface UserProfile : User

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* isBlockedByMe;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* isMyFriend;

@end
```

And finally, I have this code that it is giving me a warning:

```
[self showUserData:[User getUserFromUserPreferences]];
```

With the message:
`Incompatible pointer types sending User* to parameter of type UserProfile*`.

**Is it correct if I do this?**

```
[self showUserData:(UserProfile*)[User getUserFromUserPreferences]];
```

Or maybe, I will have memory leaks or any other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not correct. It may silent the warning but it is not ideal to do this. Usually, you  can pass derived class object as parameter to function which accepts base class instance. What you are doing is other way around.

Why this is wrong: Since you are forcible type casting base class object to derived class, now if you try to access the derived class memory space within this object it will crash at runtime. This object does not contain the derived class part.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have your derivation back-to-front.  You cannot pass a base class instance (`User`) to a method that accepts a derived class instance (`UserProfile`), but you can the other way round.

If you change the method to `showUserData:(User *)user` then it will accept both `User` and `UserProfile` instances.